# How to change the background color for these buttons one by one when I click check all connections

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, jbutton, desktop-application

[Click Here to Show the application snip pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/896Tf.png)

I want to set the background color in order to the connection status but one by one.
I do it but the background of all of them changes after the checking.
how can I do it?!!

### The Check all action performed

```
private void checkAllActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    this.cairobtnActionPerformed(evt);
    this.gizabtnActionPerformed(evt);
    this.alexbtnActionPerformed(evt);
    this.zagbtnActionPerformed(evt);
    this.asutbtnActionPerformed(evt);
    this.tantabtnActionPerformed(evt);
    this.kenabtnActionPerformed(evt);
    this.mansbtnActionPerformed(evt);
    this.meniabtnActionPerformed(evt);

}
```

### The action performed of cairobtn

```
private void cairobtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if (isSocketAliveUitlitybyCrunchify(IP String, port number)) {
        cairobtn.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
        cairobtn.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely to come from the method `isSocketAliveUitlitybyCrunchify` which either doesn't behave as you expect it to do or doen't get the expected arguments (each of which is impossible to verify with the provided information)

Side notes:

1. Your java syntax is doubtful. The line:

   ```
    if (isSocketAliveUitlitybyCrunchify(IP String, port number)) {
   ```

is clearly not java syntax (see arguments)

2. Also, if all your methods `*btnActionPerformed` performs exactly the same action, I'd advise you to make one method `btnActionPerformed(ActionEvent, Button)` and call it with each button. Plus, you can pack your buttons in an array or a `Collection` to better the code.

Comment: Thank you, I will take care of it.but my question is, How can I set the background color to the button before checking the next one? I want to check the connection of the first IP then set the background color then go to the next IP. I do it but after checking all IPs the background for all IPs changes at the same time.

Comment: Well, As I said it is very complicated to answer your question since we don't know how you built your app. Assuming that you have a list of rows each containing a button, a text input and a label, I'd loop through the rows. For each row, get the ip and port from the text input, check the connection and if successful, change the color of the button. I can't help you further without more information.